# unable to upload video through action_send intent in android 4.3

Tags: android, video, android-intent, file-upload, youtube

i am able to upload video through this code till 4.1.2 version of android. but in 4.3 this fails.

calling  shareVideo() method android displays a list of apps, but in case of selecting 
youtube from list, youtube app opens then stops without any message and in case of selecting instagram, instagram app crashes. i am  not able to upload video through any App including facebook also.

Please tell me what is the issue??

Thanks in advance.

```
public void shareVideo(View view){
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
            content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
            content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, filename);

            Uri videoURI = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);
             //Uri videoURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(filename));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("video/mp4");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoURI);
                try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Upload video via:"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                }
        }
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 4.1 android changed the mechanism of sd card path. now i can upload the the video by getting uri through the id of video file.
here is my code

```
public static String getVideoContentUriFromFilePath(Context ctx, String filePath) {

      ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
      String videoUriStr = null;
         long videoId = -1;
         Log.d("first log","Loading file " + filePath);

         // This returns us content://media/external/videos/media (or something like that)
         // I pass in "external" because that's the MediaStore's name for the external
         // storage on my device (the other possibility is "internal")
         Uri videosUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri("external");

         Log.d("second log","videosUri = " + videosUri.toString());

         String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID};

         // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
         Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(videosUri, projection, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();

         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
         videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

         Log.d("third log","Video ID is " + videoId);
         cursor.close();
         if (videoId != -1 ) videoUriStr = videosUri.toString() + "/" + videoId;
         return videoUriStr;
     }
```

and on click of your upload button
use this method-

```
public void shareVideo(View view){
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
String newPath=getVideoContentUriFromFilePath(ShareVideoActivity.this, videoPath);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                     intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Title");
                //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("video/mp4");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(newPath));
                try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Upload video via:"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                }
    }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I am using testing for KitKat android and only this code works for me, Thanks a lot